# Integrating Python Matplotlib Heatmap into a JavaScript Application

Tags: javascript, python, matplotlib, charts, webassembly

I am currently working with a medical company that is transitioning from MATLAB to JavaScript for our software solutions. As part of this process, we are looking to integrate heatmap visualizations similar to what we had in MATLAB.

like the heatmap shown in the attached image. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to incorporate a Matplotlib heatmap into our new JavaScript application. Is there an approach or a tool that allows embedding or converting these Matplotlib heatmaps for use in a JavaScript environment?

Attached is an example of the heatmap we're working with, generated in Python using Matplotlib.

[image: Example of a Python Matplotlib Heatmap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably resort to something like [MPLD3](https://mpld3.github.io/). Alternatively, you could try [Plotly JavaScript library](https://plotly.com/javascript/).

Comment: awsome where did you found the mpld3 library?

Comment: i need the difference in colors to look not pixelized so I will give a try to mpld3

Comment: You could install it with "pip install mpld3", but you should check the python version they mention here: https://mpld3.github.io/install.html